# Forwarding return value of shell script to C/C++

Tags: shell-script, c, c++, exit-status

I tried to find possible solution on Google, but all I found is explanation on how to return value, but not how to accept it in some programming language, in my case C/C++? Does anybody have idea on how to do this? Some tips?

Comment: Define what is the return value of a shell script? Are you thinking of its exit code? Details could be operating system specific.... Also, explain what "forwarding" mean to you...

Comment: Example: Shell script for initializing connection with server, if it is okay return 1 if it is not return 0. @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: This is called the exit code. Conventionally, 0 is `EXIT_SUCCESS` so is for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm focussing on Linux, but my answer probably fits for other POSIX systems.

You'll execute your shell script from a C or C++ program with some of:

- the usual mixture of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), and then `waitpid` gives you the exit code using `WEXITSTATUS` when  `WIFEXITED`
- the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) C standard library function. It returns what the internal `waipid` implementing it is returning
- the [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) POSIX standard library function. Use `WEXITSTATUS` on the result of `pclose`

Both `system` & `popen` are using the `fork`, `execve`, `waitpid` [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (and some others, see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a list).

Read any good book on Linux system programming for details (e.g. *Advanced Linux Programming* by M.Mitchell et al; you'll find [copies](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf) on the Web, or [APUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment) etc...)

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer